# Number of compositions of selection of four letters with limited repetition

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In how many ways can 4 letters of the 8-letter word 'TANZANIA' be selected if

(i) it has exactly 1 'N' and 1 'A'
(ii)it has exactly 1 'N'

in part (i) I can understand that we have to forget about all the remaining 'N's and the 'A's so we get: 3C2=3

in part (ii) if I applying the same logic the answer should be:
6C3=20 but here I am wrong. The answer given is 8 and I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: The assumption is the number of As matters, but not the identity of the particular As.  A straightforward approach is to consider four cases: no As chosen, one A chosen ,two As chosen, three As chosen.

Comment: @WillOrrick is this a rule in such combination questions that if we are given a repitition of letters we always have to break them down like you did?

Comment: No, there are alternatives.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part ii), you have to choose 3 remaining letters from T,Z,I,A,A,A.

As Will Orrick suggests, one natural method to count the ways to do this is to break it down into cases, according to the number of A's selected.

Another approach you could use is to count the number of subsets of $\{T, Z, I\}$,

since any subset of this set with n elements can be completed by choosing 3-n A's.

Since a set with $m$ elements has $2^m$ subsets, this gives an answer of $2^3=8$.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach is to use [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to solve the problem assuming that each letter can be repeated arbitrarily often.  Then use [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to subtract away compositions in which one or more letters occurs more often than it is allowed to.  In your problem, the number of compositions a three-letter selection could have, if A, T, Z, and I could repeat as many times as you like, equals the number of arrangements of three stars and three bars, and is therefore $\binom{6}{3}=20$.  The number of compositions in which T repeats two or more times equals the number of arrangements of one star and three bars and is therefore $\binom{4}{3}$.  Since Z and I are also forbidden to repeat, there are $3\cdot\binom{4}{3}=12$ illegal compositions.  Subtracting these gives $20-12=8$ legal compositions.  In general, inclusion-exclusion would require you to add back in compositions in which two or more letters repeated too often, then subtract compositions in which three or more letters repeated too often, and so on.  With a selection of only three elements, however, at most one letter can be repeated more than once.

In the most general from of your problem you have $k$ distinct letters, each with a given repetition number.  So the first letter may be repeated up to $n_1$ times, the second up to $n_2$ times, and so on.  The number of compositions of a selection of $r$ letters can be found using generating functions.  It's the coefficient of $x^r$ in the expansion of 
$$(1+x+\ldots+x^{n_1})(1+x+\ldots+x^{n_2})\ldots(1+x+\ldots+x^{n_k}).$$

Depending on $r$ and the $n_i$, there may be simplifications that allow you to determine this coefficient without brute force.  A general trick is to rewrite the generating function using the formula for geometric sum as
$$\begin{aligned}&\frac{(1-x^{n_1+1})(1-x^{n_2+1})\ldots(1-x^{n_k+1})}{(1-x)^k}\\& \qquad=(1-x^{n_1+1})(1-x^{n_2+1})\ldots(1-x^{n_k+1})\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{k+i-1}{k-1}x^i,\end{aligned}$$
where the second line has been obtained by expanding $(1-x)^{-k}$ using the generalized binomial theorem, and then doing some simplifications.

In your example, we can take $k=4$, $n_1=3$, $n_2=n_3=n_4=1$, and $r=3$ (since the N already takes one of the four spots).  Since $(1-x^4)(1-x^2)^3=1-3x^2+O(x^4)$, we need to consider the $i=3$ and $i=1$ terms in the sum.  We get $1\cdot\binom{6}{3}-3\cdot\binom{4}{3}=20-12=8.$

It is seen that this method reproduces the calculations in the opening paragraph.  The inclusion-exclusion argument is automatically taken care of by the factor in front of the summation sign, while the stars-and-bars argument is automatically handled by the binomial sum.